# String Search: find and grep and?

Tags: linux, bash, find, grep

Task:
1) find a string 'decor' inside files in a directory
2) get # of occurrence for decor for each file that has it

The first part of the problem is partially solved with `find . -type f | grep -i decor *`
But this doesn't seem `grep` for all files that are found from `find` but rather what's on top of current directory.
Do I have to use something other than `*` for `grep` to grep for files found from find?

what needs to be piped to so that it will display with a file name and the number of occurrences for decor for each file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -icH decor {} \; | grep -v :0\$
```

This will get the filename and count of each match and remove files with a count of 0 using the piped egrep

Comment: No problem! Note the edit however, without the colon it'll ignore any number ending in 0, so 10, 100 etc...

Comment: Just for the fun of it, and way beyond the scope of this exercise, I issued a `find2perl . -type f -exec grep -icH {} \;` to see if I'm willing to add the _grep -v :0\$_ part.  Looks doable, perhaps later during Jeopardy.

Answer (score 2):

"Files in a directory" does not usually mean "and iside subdirectories recursively". I would just use

```
grep -c decor *
```

If you need to search subdirectories, too, you can use find, but connect the commands differently: pipe just connects output of the first command to the input of the second. Grep does not expect list of files on its input, though.

```
find . -type f -exec grep -cH decor {} + | grep -v :0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use -exec option.
`find . -type f -exec grep decor {} \;`

or use xargs
`find . -type f | xargs -i grep decor {}`

Comment: -1: i) this breaks on filenames with white space and ii) neither of the solutions return the number of matches for `decor` which is what the OP asked for.

Answer (score 0):

TMTOWTDI - I like seeing the other variants, so here's mine as well:

```
$ find . -type f -exec egrep -li decor {} \;

$ perl -e '$c=0; while(<>){$c++ if /decor/;} continue {if(eof){print("$ARGV:$c\n"); close ARGV; $c=0;} }' *
```

Just because I felt like re-writing a Perl 1-liner that performs the same as an age old `awk` example taken from the pages of *Kernighan and Pike*.

Comment: TMTOWTDI - Sounds like something worth doing.  Note the `perl2find` _not so useful suggestion_, above - just for fun.  You already worked out my answer, with the same reference.  Bravo!

Comment: BTW - That _while(<>){} continue {if(eof){close ARGV;}_ idiom is worth memorizing.  Again, that Perl idiom is worthy of memorization.